# formatting questions for text and dates

Tags: xlsxwriter

my code looks like this

```
com = {"font_name":"Segoe UI", "font_size":11, "valign":"vcenter"}
with pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine="xlsxwriter", date_format="m/d/yyyy") as writer:
  for ctype in code_types:
    df = pd.read_parquet(f"{ctype}.parquet.gz")
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=ctype)
  
  for tab in code_types:
    sheet = writer.sheets[tab]
    fmt1 = writer.book.add_format(com|{"align":"center","num_format":"Text"})
    fmt2 = writer.book.add_format(com|{"align":"left","num_format":"Text"})
    fmt3 = writer.book.add_format(com|{"align":"center","num_format":"m/d/yyyy"})
    _ = sheet.set_column("A:B", 12, fmt1)
    _ = sheet.set_column("C:C", 60, fmt2)
    
    if tab != "diff":
      _ = sheet.set_column("D:D", 12, fmt1)
      _ = sheet.set_column("E:E", 40, fmt2)
      _ = sheet.set_column("F:G", 12, fmt3)
```

1. the date format does not work.  It is not centered and the font is not correct.  The dates are fine in the pandas dataframe.
2. how can I force num_format for all cells to be "Text" (except the date ones).  I am setting it as shown above but when I see it in Excel, they come up as custom.

Comment: It would be easier to debug/answer this with a sample data frame. Anyway, for the first part of the question: Pandas is applying a date format to  each cell which is overriding the column format you are trying to apply. For the second question: you need to apply the Excel number format for text which is usually “@“, but double check in Excel.

Comment: for the first part should I remove the `date_format` in `pd.ExcelWriter`?

Comment: Unfortunately that won’t work. It will just give you the default date format which will still override the column format.

Comment: Using `@` instead of `Text` worked perfectly for the second question.  Thank you!